# How do I use an image instead of a rectangle in HTML through JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, image, svg, rect

It seems like I've tried everything. I see that there are ways to append tags to the html script, one of which creates the `<g ...>` tag where within is located the `<rect ...>` tag. I want an image instead of the rectangle. It's all contained within an `<svg ..>` tag so I don't know if that makes a difference...

Here's an example of the code:

```
{
    key: "_updateNodes",
    value: function(t, n) {
        var e = this;
        n.forEach(function(t) {
            return t.y = t.depth * e.getNodeDepthMultiplier()
        });
        var i = (n = this.getPanningContainer().selectAll("g.node").data(n, function(t) {
            return e.getId.call(e, t.data)
            })).enter().append("g").classed("node", !0).attr("transform", function(n, e, i) {
                return "translate(" + t.y0 + "," + t.x0 + ")"
            }).on("click", function(t, n, i) {
                return e._onNodeClick.call(e, t, n, i)
            });
```

Maybe this will help more. You'll notice the `<image ...>` tag in there; no image appears.

```
<svg class="mitch-d3-tree default boxed-tree" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" viewBox="0 0 960 800" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
   <g class="view" transform="translate(100,40)">
      <g class="panningContainer" transform="translate(210,0) scale(1)">
         <g class="node expanded" transform="translate(0,360)">
            <g class="body-group">
               <rect class="body-box" width="200" height="75" y="-37.5"></rect>
            </g>
            <image class="title-group" transform="translate(-33.333333333333336, -57.5)">
               <image src="/static/FCA_Black.png" width="100" height="40"></image>
               <g class="d3plus-textBox" id="d3plus-textBox-0" transform="translate(5, 8.48) rotate(0, 45, 18)" style="pointer-events: auto; fill-opacity: 0.3;">
                  <text dominant-baseline="alphabetic" unicode-bidi="bidi-override" aria-hidden="false" dir="ltr" fill="black" text-anchor="middle" font-family="Arial Narrow" font-size="16px" font-weight="700" x="45px" y="16px" opacity="1" style="baseline-shift: 0%; font-family: &quot;Arial Narrow&quot;; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 700; opacity: 1;">FCA</text>
               </g>
            </image>
         </g>
         <g class="node collapsed" transform="translate(300, 24)">
            <g class="body-group">
               <rect class="body-box" width="200" height="75" y="-37.5"></rect>
            </g>
            <image class="title-group" transform="translate(-33.333333333333336, -57.5)">
               <image src="/static/FCA_Black.png" width="100" height="40"></image>
               <g class="d3plus-textBox" id="d3plus-textBox-0" transform="translate(5, 8.48) rotate(0, 45, 18)" style="pointer-events: auto; fill-opacity: 0.3;">
                  <text dominant-baseline="alphabetic" unicode-bidi="bidi-override" aria-hidden="false" dir="ltr" fill="black" text-anchor="middle" font-family="Arial Narrow" font-size="16px" font-weight="700" x="45px" y="16px" opacity="1" style="baseline-shift: 0%; font-family: &quot;Arial Narrow&quot;; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 700; opacity: 1;">Jeep</text>
               </g>
            </image>
         </g>
         <g class="node collapsed" transform="translate(300, 72)">
            <g class="body-group">
               <rect class="body-box" width="200" height="75" y="-37.5"></rect>
            </g>
            <image class="title-group" transform="translate(-33.333333333333336, -57.5)">
               <image src="/static/FCA_Black.png" width="100" height="40"></image>
               <g class="d3plus-textBox" id="d3plus-textBox-0" transform="translate(5, 8.48) rotate(0, 45, 18)" style="pointer-events: auto; fill-opacity: 0.3;">
                  <text dominant-baseline="alphabetic" unicode-bidi="bidi-override" aria-hidden="false" dir="ltr" fill="black" text-anchor="middle" font-family="Arial Narrow" font-size="16px" font-weight="700" x="45px" y="16px" opacity="1" style="baseline-shift: 0%; font-family: &quot;Arial Narrow&quot;; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 700; opacity: 1;">Dodge</text>
               </g>
            </image>
         </g>
         <g class="node collapsed" transform="translate(300, 120)">
            <g class="body-group">
               <rect class="body-box" width="200" height="75" y="-37.5"></rect>
            </g>
            <image class="title-group" transform="translate(-33.333333333333336, -57.5)">
               <image src="/static/FCA_Black.png" width="100" height="40"></image>
               <g class="d3plus-textBox" id="d3plus-textBox-0" transform="translate(5, 8.48) rotate(0, 45, 18)" style="pointer-events: auto; fill-opacity: 0.3;">
                  <text dominant-baseline="alphabetic" unicode-bidi="bidi-override" aria-hidden="false" dir="ltr" fill="black" text-anchor="middle" font-family="Arial Narrow" font-size="16px" font-weight="700" x="45px" y="16px" opacity="1" style="baseline-shift: 0%; font-family: &quot;Arial Narrow&quot;; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 700; opacity: 1;">Ram</text>
               </g>
            </image>
         </g>
         <g class="node collapsed" transform="translate(300, 168)">
            <g class="body-group">
               <rect class="body-box" width="200" height="75" y="-37.5"></rect>
            </g>
            <image class="title-group" transform="translate(-33.333333333333336, -57.5)">
               <image src="/static/FCA_Black.png" width="100" height="40"></image>
               <g class="d3plus-textBox" id="d3plus-textBox-0" transform="translate(5, 8.48) rotate(0, 45, 18)" style="pointer-events: auto; fill-opacity: 0.3;">
                  <text dominant-baseline="alphabetic" unicode-bidi="bidi-override" aria-hidden="false" dir="ltr" fill="black" text-anchor="middle" font-family="Arial Narrow" font-size="16px" font-weight="700" x="45px" y="16px" opacity="1" style="baseline-shift: 0%; font-family: &quot;Arial Narrow&quot;; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 700; opacity: 1;">Fleet</text>
               </g>
            </image>
         </g>
         <g class="node collapsed" transform="translate(300, 216)">
            <g class="body-group">
               <rect class="body-box" width="200" height="75" y="-37.5"></rect>
            </g>
            <image class="title-group" transform="translate(-33.333333333333336, -57.5)">
               <image src="/static/FCA_Black.png" width="100" height="40"></image>
               <g class="d3plus-textBox" id="d3plus-textBox-0" transform="translate(5, 8.48) rotate(0, 45, 18)" style="pointer-events: auto; fill-opacity: 0.3;">
                  <text dominant-baseline="alphabetic" unicode-bidi="bidi-override" aria-hidden="false" dir="ltr" fill="black" text-anchor="middle" font-family="Arial Narrow" font-size="16px" font-weight="700" x="45px" y="16px" opacity="1" style="baseline-shift: 0%; font-family: &quot;Arial Narrow&quot;; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 700; opacity: 1;">Chrysler</text>
               </g>
            </image>
         </g>
         <g class="node collapsed" transform="translate(300, 264)">
            <g class="body-group">
               <rect class="body-box" width="200" height="75" y="-37.5"></rect>
            </g>
            <image class="title-group" transform="translate(-33.333333333333336, -57.5)">
               <image src="/static/FCA_Black.png" width="100" height="40"></image>
               <g class="d3plus-textBox" id="d3plus-textBox-0" transform="translate(5, 8.48) rotate(0, 45, 18)" style="pointer-events: auto; fill-opacity: 0.3;">
                  <text dominant-baseline="alphabetic" unicode-bidi="bidi-override" aria-hidden="false" dir="ltr" fill="black" text-anchor="middle" font-family="Arial Narrow" font-size="16px" font-weight="700" x="45px" y="16px" opacity="1" style="baseline-shift: 0%; font-family: &quot;Arial Narrow&quot;; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 700; opacity: 1;">Fiat</text>
               </g>
            </image>
         </g>
         <g class="node collapsed" transform="translate(300, 312)">
            <g class="body-group">
               <rect class="body-box" width="200" height="75" y="-37.5"></rect>
            </g>
            <image class="title-group" transform="translate(-33.333333333333336, -57.5)">
               <image src="/static/FCA_Black.png" width="100" height="40"></image>
               <g class="d3plus-textBox" id="d3plus-textBox-0" transform="translate(5, 8.48) rotate(0, 45, 18)" style="pointer-events: auto; fill-opacity: 0.3;">
                  <text dominant-baseline="alphabetic" unicode-bidi="bidi-override" aria-hidden="false" dir="ltr" fill="black" text-anchor="middle" font-family="Arial Narrow" font-size="16px" font-weight="700" x="45px" y="16px" opacity="1" style="baseline-shift: 0%; font-family: &quot;Arial Narrow&quot;; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 700; opacity: 1;">Alfa Romeo</text>
               </g>
            </image>
         </g>
         <g class="node collapsed" transform="translate(300, 360)">
            <g class="body-group">
               <rect class="body-box" width="200" height="75" y="-37.5"></rect>
            </g>
            <image class="title-group" transform="translate(-33.333333333333336, -57.5)">
               <image src="/static/FCA_Black.png" width="100" height="40"></image>
               <g class="d3plus-textBox" id="d3plus-textBox-0" transform="translate(5, 8.48) rotate(0, 45, 18)" style="pointer-events: auto; fill-opacity: 0.3;">
                  <text dominant-baseline="alphabetic" unicode-bidi="bidi-override" aria-hidden="false" dir="ltr" fill="black" text-anchor="middle" font-family="Arial Narrow" font-size="16px" font-weight="700" x="45px" y="16px" opacity="1" style="baseline-shift: 0%; font-family: &quot;Arial Narrow&quot;; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 700; opacity: 1;">Mopar</text>
               </g>
            </image>
         </g>
         <g class="node collapsed" transform="translate(300, 408)">
            <g class="body-group">
               <rect class="body-box" width="200" height="75" y="-37.5"></rect>
            </g>
            <image class="title-group" transform="translate(-33.333333333333336, -57.5)">
               <image src="/static/FCA_Black.png" width="100" height="40"></image>
               <g class="d3plus-textBox" id="d3plus-textBox-0" transform="translate(5, 8.48) rotate(0, 45, 18)" style="pointer-events: auto; fill-opacity: 0.3;">
                  <text dominant-baseline="alphabetic" unicode-bidi="bidi-override" aria-hidden="false" dir="ltr" fill="black" text-anchor="middle" font-family="Arial Narrow" font-size="16px" font-weight="700" x="45px" y="16px" opacity="1" style="baseline-shift: 0%; font-family: &quot;Arial Narrow&quot;; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 700; opacity: 1;">Maserati</text>
               </g>
            </image>
         </g>
         <g class="node collapsed" transform="translate(300, 456)">
            <g class="body-group">
               <rect class="body-box" width="200" height="75" y="-37.5"></rect>
            </g>
            <image class="title-group" transform="translate(-33.333333333333336, -57.5)">
               <image src="/static/FCA_Black.png" width="100" height="40"></image>
               <g class="d3plus-textBox" id="d3plus-textBox-0" transform="translate(5, 0.19999999999999996) rotate(0, 45, 18)" style="pointer-events: auto; fill-opacity: 0.3;">
                  <text dominant-baseline="alphabetic" unicode-bidi="bidi-override" aria-hidden="false" dir="ltr" fill="black" text-anchor="middle" font-family="Arial Narrow" font-size="15px" font-weight="700" x="45px" y="15px" opacity="1" style="baseline-shift: 0%; font-family: &quot;Arial Narrow&quot;; font-size: 15px; font-weight: 700; opacity: 1;">Ram</text>
                  <text dominant-baseline="alphabetic" unicode-bidi="bidi-override" aria-hidden="false" dir="ltr" fill="black" text-anchor="middle" font-family="Arial Narrow" font-size="15px" font-weight="700" x="45px" y="33px" opacity="1" style="baseline-shift: 0%; font-family: &quot;Arial Narrow&quot;; font-size: 15px; font-weight: 700; opacity: 1;">Commercial</text>
               </g>
            </image>
         </g>
         <g class="node collapsed" transform="translate(300, 504)">
            <g class="body-group">
               <rect class="body-box" width="200" height="75" y="-37.5"></rect>
            </g>
            <image class="title-group" transform="translate(-33.333333333333336, -57.5)">
               <image src="/static/FCA_Black.png" width="100" height="40"></image>
               <g class="d3plus-textBox" id="d3plus-textBox-0" transform="translate(5, 8.48) rotate(0, 45, 18)" style="pointer-events: auto; fill-opacity: 0.3;">
                  <text dominant-baseline="alphabetic" unicode-bidi="bidi-override" aria-hidden="false" dir="ltr" fill="black" text-anchor="middle" font-family="Arial Narrow" font-size="16px" font-weight="700" x="45px" y="16px" opacity="1" style="baseline-shift: 0%; font-family: &quot;Arial Narrow&quot;; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 700; opacity: 1;">Business Link</text>
               </g>
            </image>
         </g>
         <g class="node collapsed" transform="translate(300, 552)">
            <g class="body-group">
               <rect class="body-box" width="200" height="75" y="-37.5"></rect>
            </g>
            <image class="title-group" transform="translate(-33.333333333333336, -57.5)">
               <image src="/static/FCA_Black.png" width="100" height="40"></image>
               <g class="d3plus-textBox" id="d3plus-textBox-0" transform="translate(5, 8.48) rotate(0, 45, 18)" style="pointer-events: auto; fill-opacity: 0.3;">
                  <text dominant-baseline="alphabetic" unicode-bidi="bidi-override" aria-hidden="false" dir="ltr" fill="black" text-anchor="middle" font-family="Arial Narrow" font-size="16px" font-weight="700" x="45px" y="16px" opacity="1" style="baseline-shift: 0%; font-family: &quot;Arial Narrow&quot;; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 700; opacity: 1;">CPOV</text>
               </g>
            </image>
         </g>
         <g class="node collapsed" transform="translate(300, 600)">
            <g class="body-group">
               <rect class="body-box" width="200" height="75" y="-37.5"></rect>
            </g>
            <image class="title-group" transform="translate(-33.333333333333336, -57.5)">
               <image src="/static/FCA_Black.png" width="100" height="40"></image>
               <g class="d3plus-textBox" id="d3plus-textBox-0" transform="translate(5, 8.48) rotate(0, 45, 18)" style="pointer-events: auto; fill-opacity: 0.3;">
                  <text dominant-baseline="alphabetic" unicode-bidi="bidi-override" aria-hidden="false" dir="ltr" fill="black" text-anchor="middle" font-family="Arial Narrow" font-size="16px" font-weight="700" x="45px" y="16px" opacity="1" style="baseline-shift: 0%; font-family: &quot;Arial Narrow&quot;; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 700; opacity: 1;">Uconnect</text>
               </g>
            </image>
         </g>
         <g class="node collapsed" transform="translate(300, 648)">
            <g class="body-group">
               <rect class="body-box" width="200" height="75" y="-37.5"></rect>
            </g>
            <image class="title-group" transform="translate(-33.333333333333336, -57.5)">
               <image src="/static/FCA_Black.png" width="100" height="40"></image>
               <g class="d3plus-textBox" id="d3plus-textBox-0" transform="translate(5, 9.2) rotate(0, 45, 18)" style="pointer-events: auto; fill-opacity: 0.3;">
                  <text dominant-baseline="alphabetic" unicode-bidi="bidi-override" aria-hidden="false" dir="ltr" fill="black" text-anchor="middle" font-family="Arial Narrow" font-size="15px" font-weight="700" x="45px" y="15px" opacity="1" style="baseline-shift: 0%; font-family: &quot;Arial Narrow&quot;; font-size: 15px; font-weight: 700; opacity: 1;">Maserati CPOV</text>
               </g>
            </image>
         </g>
         <g class="node collapsed" transform="translate(300, 696)">
            <g class="body-group">
               <rect class="body-box" width="200" height="75" y="-37.5"></rect>
            </g>
            <image class="title-group" transform="translate(-33.333333333333336, -57.5)">
               <image src="/static/FCA_Black.png" width="100" height="40"></image>
               <g class="d3plus-textBox" id="d3plus-textBox-0" transform="translate(5, 8.48) rotate(0, 45, 18)" style="pointer-events: auto; fill-opacity: 0.3;">
                  <text dominant-baseline="alphabetic" unicode-bidi="bidi-override" aria-hidden="false" dir="ltr" fill="black" text-anchor="middle" font-family="Arial Narrow" font-size="16px" font-weight="700" x="45px" y="16px" opacity="1" style="baseline-shift: 0%; font-family: &quot;Arial Narrow&quot;; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 700; opacity: 1;">RMF</text>
               </g>
            </image>
         </g>
         <path class="link" d="M300,24C250,24,250,360,200,360"></path>
         <path class="link" d="M300,72C250,72,250,360,200,360"></path>
         <path class="link" d="M300,120C250,120,250,360,200,360"></path>
         <path class="link" d="M300,168C250,168,250,360,200,360"></path>
         <path class="link" d="M300,216C250,216,250,360,200,360"></path>
         <path class="link" d="M300,264C250,264,250,360,200,360"></path>
         <path class="link" d="M300,312C250,312,250,360,200,360"></path>
         <path class="link" d="M300,360C250,360,250,360,200,360"></path>
         <path class="link" d="M300,408C250,408,250,360,200,360"></path>
         <path class="link" d="M300,456C250,456,250,360,200,360"></path>
         <path class="link" d="M300,504C250,504,250,360,200,360"></path>
         <path class="link" d="M300,552C250,552,250,360,200,360"></path>
         <path class="link" d="M300,600C250,600,250,360,200,360"></path>
         <path class="link" d="M300,648C250,648,250,360,200,360"></path>
         <path class="link" d="M300,696C250,696,250,360,200,360"></path>
      </g>
   </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Yes `svg` have a `image` tag that allows you to put an image (which is different of the `img` html tag). See: https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/SVG/Element/image and also that so post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10859257/how-can-i-add-an-image-element-to-the-svg-dom . Hope it helps.

Comment: that didn't help unfortunately

Comment: I just updated the question

Comment: It looks like your images have a translate transform that moves them out of the viewBox, so they won't be visible.

Comment: You're using `src` while it must be `xlink:href` . As I said, svg `<image>` tag is not the same than html  `<img>` tag.

Comment: Both of you helped answer the question. It worked. Thank you!